# Как подключить shell-скрипт к php?

Tags: shell, php

Есть у меня скриптик `php`, который отсылает данные в гугл распознание голоса.
И у него есть `Shell` скрипт:

```
apt-get install sox
apt-get install flac 

#!/bin/bash

while [ true ]; do
     rec -q -c 1 -r 16000 current.wav silence 1 0.3 3% 1 0.3 3%
     flac -f -s current.wav -o current.flac
     php texttocmd.php
done
```

Как подключить его к php?

Comment: Нужно его запустить? Ну так и запускаете обычными средствами PHP, какой-нибудь функцией из семейства exec. Или лучше запустить sh, передав в качестве параметра имя этого скрипта

     sh my_script

Comment: Спс                  Большое

Comment: Блин вот что получаеться http://golosovoimir.16mb.com/index1.php

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться функцией [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php):

```
exec ( "команда для запуска скрипта" );
```